# I am using getValue and getting error sheet.DataAsArr.getValue is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to test a row column for if the Checkbox is checked and getting a error i have inclued the part of the script below the line is

```
             if  ( sheetDataAsArr.getValue(i+2, U) == true ) {
```

Here is the code below do i have to use getRange and getValue(i+2, U ) == true ) please advise ?

The error is sheet.DataAsArr.getValue is not a function

```
    // lets get all the data in the active Sheet (or whichever Sheet)
    const sheetDataAsArr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues(); // 2020Members 


    // Start at first row 
    var i = 0;

    // Mark the rows as apporved  
     sheetDataAsArr.forEach(function(row,i)     {   
     // The i is a index 
     // 

     var V = 22;   // V defined here
     var U = 21;   // U defined here


       if  ( sheetDataAsArr.getValue(i+2, U) == true ) {    


          // method getRange(row, column, optNumRows, optNumColumns)
          ws.getRange(i+2, V).setValue(appoved); // Note: argument 3, 4, is optional actual worksheet 
          // The i+2 is because the data starts on the second row first row are headers    
          // return; 
          Logger.log('INDEX i is :' + i);
          Logger.log('ROW row is :' + row[0]);  // The email address 

          i++; // Must auto increment i  

        } 
        i++; // Must auto increment i  

      } 

     } ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is passing two argumentos to `getValue` but it should not have any argument at all.

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing quite a bit here but I think this is what you were shooting for:

```
function getAllData() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr=2;
  const rg=sh.getRange(sr,21,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,1);
  const org=sh.getRange(sr,22,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,1);
  const ovs=org.getValues();
  const vs=rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){if(r[0]==true){ovs[i][0]='Approved';}});
  org.setValues(ovs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

This is a quick and easy implementation of what you were aiming for abstracted so that anyone can easily adapt it to their specific situation.

> Check the values of a range of checkboxes and if they are marked then set the values of a specific range.

This piece of code uses a function `onEdit()` which will change the values whenever the user in the spreadsheet marks the checkbox. If you do not want [this trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to be active just change the function name. In this case I am checking a range of checkboxes from `A1:A100` and setting the values of `B1:B100` if the checkbox in column `A` is marked. The code has self explanatory comments:

```js
function onEdit() {
  // Get sheet by name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  // Get our range where we have the checkboxes. GetValues returns an array of arrays
  // for rows and columns, if we flatten it using the flat function we will end up with the
  // desired 1D array which lets us avoid usingthe forEach function (and wrting less code ! :D)
  var checkboxRangeValues = sheet.getRange('A1:A100').getValues().flat();
  
  // for each cell in the check box range
  for(i=0;i<checkboxRangeValues.length;i++){
  
  // check if that specific cell is marked
    if(checkboxRangeValues[i]==true){
    // set the value of your desired cell to approved
    // (note this must be a string if it is a word), in this case we are setting to approved
    // the cells in the column B (2), i+1 is because our indexes start by 0 while our row
    // numbers actually start by 1
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue('approved');
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)